# 2020!(Not exactly though)

Tags: knowledge, visual, number-sequence, rebus

The images in the rectangle will help you replace the question marks with the correct numbers!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to the Rebus

> **First Image:** Country Music
>  **Second Image:** Not Music
>  **First + Second Images:** Country
>  **Third Image:** Code
>  **Overall:** Country Code

Triangles

> Now that we know we are looking for country codes we can try to extract these from the triangles. If we assign letters to number A=1, B=2, C=3, etc, and read the numbers in each triangle in the order left, top, right we find the following codes,
>
>  **CHN** = China
>  **IND** = India
>  **USA** = United States
>  **IDN** = Indonesia
>  **PAK** = Pakistan
>
>  We recognise these as the five most populous countries in the world.

Lists of numbers

> We notice that there are five lists of numbers and five countries mentioned so it seems that each country corresponds to a list. The first two list have ten entries and the rest have nine. If we were to concatenate the digits in each list, the first two numbers would be over one billion - this suggests that we might be looking at population counts for each country.
>
>  Population data is updated often and there are often disagreements between different sources (because of the high variance in estimation) but I think I've found the source of the numbers used for this puzzle: https://www.internetworldstats.com/stats8.htm
>
>  China, 1,4,**3**,**9**,3,2,3,7,**7**,6
>  India, 1,3,8,0,**0**,**0**,4,3,8,5
>  United States, 3,**3**,1,**0**,0,2,6,5,1
>  Indonesia, 2,7,3,**5**,**2**,**3**,6,1,5
>  Pakistan, **2**,2,**0**,8,9,**2**,3,4,0

Comment: Had forgotten about this one :) This is correct. Well done!